# If $P$ is sufficient for $Q$: $(P \Rightarrow Q)$ or $(Q \Rightarrow P)$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, terminology

For the given statement:

*" A sufficient condition for network failure is that the central switch
goes down."*

Let $Q$ be the network failure, and $P$ be the central switch shutting down. Then symbolically, the statement would be: $P$ is sufficient for $Q$

Can I say that: "if $P$ then $Q$" so that the antecedent is ***P*** and the consequent is ***Q***? or is it the opposite?

Comment: "$P$ sufficient for $Q$" means "$P\implies Q$" (which also means "$Q$ is necessary for $P$").

Comment: If $P$ implies $Q$ then $P$ is sufficient condition for $Q$.

Comment: "P is sufficienct for Q" would mean if we have $P$ that would be enough to show $Q$.  So $P\implies Q$".  "P is *necessary* for Q" would mean we can't ever have $Q$ *without* $P$.  So $Q\implies P$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In essence, yes. Note that because something is a sufficient condition, does not mean that it is a *necessary* condition. Example: A sufficient condition for the road to be wet, is for it to be raining. *But*, it isn't a necessary one. It could be that I spilled a bottle of water on the road.

In your example, "**if P then Q**" is correct: If the central switch is goes down, then the network is down as well. But if the the central switch is up, it does not mean that the network is not down. "**if not-P then not-Q**" would then be incorrect, because it could be the case that there is no power. However, you could say "**if not-Q then not-P**" (i.e. the contrapositive: If the network is up, then the central switch must be up as well)

Answer (score 0):

The following statements are logically equivalent:

- A implies B
- If A, then B
- A only if B
- A is sufficient of B
- B if A
- B is necessary for A

My favourite example: A = Raining, B = Cloudy

- Raining implies cloudy
- If raining, then cloudy
- Raining only if cloudy
- Raining is sufficient for cloudy
- Cloudy if raining
- Cloudy is necessary for raining

Note that rain does NOT *cause* cloudiness. "Raining implies cloudy" means only that, at the moment, it is *not both* raining and not cloudy (an example material implication in classical logic).